# How to plot a histogram as a scatter plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, histogram, scatter-plot

The y axis should be frequency (which is the histogram part) while the x axis is the xdata used to plot the histogram. Essentially what I need is exactly a histogram but instead of bars, there should be points.

Comment: Start by reading the output of `help histogram` and `help scatter`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that using the `histcounts` command. It's like the `histogram` command, but instead of plotting the data, it returns the number in each bin and the bin edges. You can then plot that as points using the general `plot` command.

```
x = randn(1,1000); %Generate some data to plot

figure(1); clf;
subplot(2,1,1); hold on;
h = histogram(x,'normalization','probability');
title('Plotted as a histogram');
ylabel('Frequency');

subplot(2,1,2); hold on;
[N, edges] = histcounts(x,'normalization','probability');
centers = (edges(1:end-1) + edges(2:end))./2; %histcounts gives the bin edges, but we want to plot the bin centers
plot(centers,N,'ko');
title('Plotted as points');
ylabel('Frequency');
```